# Spring Boot example for @NotEmpty annotaion

Tags: spring-boot, freemarker

I am developing spring boot application which has freemarker for UI.
I want to use @NotEmpty annotation for radio button. e.g.
"input type="radio"

I can see examples on internet but they are with form tag(spring tag).

Can someone give me example for above without form tag.

Comment: Have a look here: <@spring.showErrors "<br>"/>

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<@spring.formRadioButtons "x.y"/>
<@spring.showErrors "<br>"/>
```

to display the validation messages.

Have a look at this tutorial:

https://hellokoding.com/form-data-binding-and-validation-example-with-java-spring-boot-and-freemarker/

Comment: I am using <@spring . Do you have any idea to achieve this with <input type ="radio"

Comment: why don't you use @spring.formRadioButtons?

Comment: Due to some limitations to use of CSS

Comment: so then you will not be able to make use of the validation. What kind of CSS limitations?

Comment: we have existing css for div tag. earlier we have used this div tag for each radio button but now if we use @spring:radiobuttons .css are getting applied to first radio button only.

Comment: But this is something that can be easely fixed

Comment: We have fixed the css issue. Thanks